# Unexpected System.CalloutException in test while using startTest method

Tags: unit-test, dml

```
@isTest
global class xxx_UT implements WebServiceMock {
  static {
    Account account = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
    insert account;
    Qwerty__c q = new Qwerty__c();
    insert q;
    User u = new User();
    insert u;
  }

  @isTest
  static void tt() {
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new xxx_UT());
    ss connection = new ss();
    String result = connection.dd('uuu', 2);
    Test.stopTest();
  }

  global void doInvoke(
    Object stub,
    Object request,
    Map<String, Object> response,
    String endpoint,
    String soapAction,
    String requestName,
    String responseNS,
    String responseName,
    String responseType
  ) {
      zz response_x = new zz();
      response_x.xx = 'test';
      response.put('response_x', response_x);
  }
}
```

When run this test I have "You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" at line in method "dd"

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/dd',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'dd',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'ddResponse',
              'ddResponse_element'}
            );
```

ss class or it's dd method don't have any DML - it's a generated class from wsdl. Test class has version 20.

While I was writing this question, I found out interesting thing - when I comment out insert q; line, the error vanish. The Qwerty__c object is from Managed Package.

What might be the problem with this insertion?

Comment: facing the similar problem, as a workaround used used 'isrunningtest' but looking for real solution

Comment: @NickSFDC, but this startTest and stopTest method actually help to avoid isRunningTest method in methods with business logic. Maybe, I will end up with isRunningTest method...

Comment: Yeah, but it leads to decrease in code coverage !!